# Hot to get all items in observer on remove product action on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, event-observer, mini-cart

I created an observer on `sales_quote_remove_item` action, and i want to take all the product that remains in cart after I remove a product, and i can't.

The only thing that i can take in observer it's the product that i want to remove from order.

My observer look like this:

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class CheckoutSessionRemoveObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    private $_sessionManager;

     public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager $sessionManager
    ) {
        $this->_sessionManager = $sessionManager;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\
    Observer $observer)
    {    
        $quote = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        $sku = $quote->getSku();
        print_r($sku); die();
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how can i take all the product that remains in the cart after deleting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this in your observer

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{    
    $quoteItem = $observer->getQuoteItem();
    $sku = $quoteItem->getSku();
    $quote = $quoteItem->getQuote();
    $allItems = $quote->getAllItems(); //or getAllVisibleItems() if you don't want duplicates for configurable products;
    foreach ($allItems as $item) {
        //do something with item
        $itemSku = $item->getSku();
        $product = $item->getProduct();
        //...
    }
    print_r($sku); die();
}
```

Comment: Thnak you very much. it works. if i want to make the same thing in checkout_cart_update_items_after action, i can use the same code?

Comment: for that event you get as parameter a `Cart` object. In order to get the `Quote` object you need to do `$quote = $observer->getCart()->getQuote()`. The rest of the code, you can reuse.

Comment: do you have any idea why i recive wrong id when a try to get product id ? $product_id = $item->getId();

Comment: an recive unexisting id's

Comment: `$item->getProduct()->getId()` or `$item->getProductId()`